# How can I set visible = true for only this record in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to be able to add more fields depending on how many cars this employee have.

I tried set Me.textfield.Visible = True
So it initiates with Visible = False, then when the button '+' is pressed the textfield is shown, but it won't work how I expected

When I do :

```
Private Sub mostracarro2_Click()

    Me.labelmodelo2.Visible = True
    Me.Modelo2.Visible = True

    Me.labelplaca2.Visible = True
    Me.Placa2.Visible = True

    Me.mostracarro3.Visible = True
End Sub
```

All of the others records fields are set for true, but I just wanted to change this record field.

If a employee has just one single car I want just one text field to be shown.

If a employee has more than one car I want to have two text field to be shown.

how can I do it in MS Access 2010?

Comment: Are you working with a Continuous Form?

Comment: Multiple fields for cars sounds like non-normalized data structure. What if employee has more than 2 cars?

Comment: Use a table for cars, with the employees ID as foreignkey (1:n) and have a subform on the form for the cars of employee (unlimited)! If you insist on that structure, you can use conditional format or Detail_Paint event to make control invisible.

Comment: I love data structures that force awful pivot queries later down the road lol